# Firefox won't play video on one site, says I need to try another browser ubuntu 20.04

Tags: video

I have 20.04 on two computers.  One will play channels on https://ustv247.tv/ and the other (new install) says it is unable to play and that I should try another browser.  I use Firefox on both.  I don't get it.   When installing on the 2nd computer, I did select the option to install the extra video drivers.

Comment: you can install the codecs from softwarecenter,the first one to install is the chromium-ffmpeg and you might want to install some of the gstreamer codecs too and you should be able to play just about anything.

Comment: I don't know where to find them.  I clicked on the icon for 'Software" and looked in the video section and there is nothing there for  either 'chromium' or 'gstreamer' .   I also don't see anything that says 'codec'.   I must be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: in software center click on the search(magnifying glass upper left corner) and search codecs that is all and you will find it.

Comment: I had searched for 'video codecs' before.   But, from your suggestion I found them and installed them and rebooted and it still doesn't work.   I have that c hromium and I installed the Q5 from gstreamer, that was the first in the list and there were 7 others already installed, but there are still a few that aren't installed.  Should I just install them all?   I never had this problem on any other installation before, I had 2 earlier computers and no problems.  Strange.

Comment: so you are unable to play any of the channels on your list on one of your computers? i am not sure how to diagnose this problem maybe somebody else here can tell you what to look for.